# How can I tell if my Oracle system is set to support Unicode or multibyte characters?

Tags: oracle, unicode, plsql, oracle11g

I understand that Oracle supports multiple character sets, but how can determine if the current 11g system where I work has that functionality enabled?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

```
SELECT *
  FROM v$nls_parameters
 WHERE parameter LIKE '%CHARACTERSET';
```

will show you the database and national character set.  The database character set controls the encoding of data in `CHAR` and `VARCHAR2` columns.  If the database supports Unicode in those columns, the database character set should be AL32UTF8 (or UTF8 in some rare cases).  The national character set controls the encoding of data in `NCHAR` and `NVARCHAR2` columns.  If the database character set does not support Unicode, you may be able to store Unicode data in columns with these data types but that generally adds complexity to the system-- applications may have to change to support the national character set.

Answer (score 4):

Unicode is a character encoding system that defines every character in most of the spoken languages in the world, Support for Unicode in Oracle Database:

```
Character Set   Supported in RDBMS Release  Unicode Encoding
AL24UTFFSS      7.2 - 8i                    UTF-8
UTF8            8.0 - 11g                   UTF-8
UTFE            8.0 - 11g                   UTF-EBCDIC
AL32UTF8        9i - 11g                    UTF-8
AL16UTF16       9i - 11g                    UTF-16
```

To Make sure your database is Unicode, please check the value of "NLS_CHARACTERSET" Parameter and it should be AL32UTF8 or AL16UTF16 from above list.

```
SQL>
SQL> SELECT * FROM v$nls_parameters WHERE parameter='NLS_CHARACTERSET';

PARAMETER                   VALUE               CON_ID
--------------------------- ------------------- ----------
NLS_CHARACTERSET            AL32UTF8            0
```

To Change the value of Parameter, Please Take the Fullback up because  ALTER DATABASE statement cannot be rolled back and the Use following statements:

```
SHUTDOWN IMMEDIATE
STARTUP MOUNT;
ALTER SYSTEM ENABLE RESTRICTED SESSION;
ALTER SYSTEM SET JOB_QUEUE_PROCESSES=0;
ALTER SYSTEM SET AQ_TM_PROCESSES=0;
ALTER DATABASE OPEN;
ALTER DATABASE CHARACTER SET AL32UTF8;
SHUTDOWN IMMEDIATE;
STARTUP;
```

Comment: Command `ALTER DATABASE CHARACTER SET ...` is de-supported since Oracle 10R1, you may destroy your database (see example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15224015/oracle-11g-xe-greek-character-set-not-displaying). However, if the old character set is `US7ASCII` then this approach may work exceptionally.

Answer (score 0):

The Rajesh's answer is almost exact. I was taken interest of AL24UTFFSS charset. A old Oracle 7.2 documentation (A20327-2, Oracle7 Server
Reference, page 3-31) is stated:

> The character set name for UTF2 is AL24UTFFSS. Conversion between UTF2
> and other existing character sets is provided in this release of
> Oracle Server. Conversion between UTF2 and singlebyte character sets
> is done through an internal number matching mechanism; conversion
> between UTF2 and multibyte character sets is done with conversion
> functions and tables.
>
> Clients should be aware that AL24UTFFSS is now officially supported as
> a new character set. Since the encoding scheme of UTF2 is very similar
> to some existing character sets, no major impact on existing products
> is expected.

But Rajesh said: AL24UTFFSS is UTF8.
I know that UCS2 is obsolete term for UTF16 (i.e. AL16UTF16).
Personally I is not acquainted with "UTF2" term, but "AL24" prefix hints at some 3-byte charset. It not looks like UTF8.