# Chinese characters are supported by my oracle database?

Tags: unicode, oracle11g, oracle-sqldeveloper

****How can I confirm that Chinese characters are supported by my oracle  database ?****

Comment: What have you tried so far? I have heard that googling sometimes do the magic.

Comment: Yaroslav Shabalin, I have googled it already, without any luck. Please give me a valid answer if you have.

Comment: See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9703573/2899629) to understand how to retrieve current NLS parameters. [The full list](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e10729/applocaledata.htm#i635047) of possible character sets. I presume that to support chinese database should have either `AL32UTF8`, or some appropriate national character set from the list above.

Comment: @YaroslavShabalin ---I was already running this query, 'SELECT *   FROM v$nls_parameters  WHERE parameter LIKE '%CHARACTERSET''--was geting AL32UTF8 as value of NLS_CHARACTERSET parameter, but wasn't aware that it has universal character set coverage(so chinese characters are also supported ). Got this confirmation from my DBA. Thanks for your help though.

Comment: Glad that it was helpful. Please, mark question as answered then.

Answer (score 0):

See this answer to understand how to retrieve current NLS parameters. The full list of possible character sets. I presume that to support chinese database should have either AL32UTF8, or some appropriate national character set from the list above.