# Why inverted question marks(¿) are saving when trying to save hyphen(-) in oracle? How to get rid of this?

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

Whenever i try to save any record in oracle with hyphen in the middle of sentence then it is saving as inverted question mark in oracle. This is happening only when i execute this insert query with other queries combined and execute all at a time using SQL plus application. But this is not happening when i execute insert query individually using SQL developer. Why is this happening and what is the solution for this.?

Comment: What do you get in SQLPlus for a "select '-' result from dual;" command? There maybe some problem with your default escaping, hyphen should not be a special char by default, I think.

Comment: When i try to get results with '-' in sql plus it is returning 0 records.

Comment: The hyphen on your keyboard is ASCII 45 and is supported by all character sets. You must be pasting an extended hyphen or something funny.

Comment: Entering the above select you should not get 0 records, DUAL do has one record. Type exactly that command, you must get one result row.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SQL Developer is Java based which does not use `NLS_LANG` settings but SQL*Plus does, so you have to set `NLS_LANG` properly.

You did not tell us which hyphen you use, see answer from MT0. In your question you took `U+002D (CHR(45))` which is in ASCII - for sure this does make any problem.

SQL*Plus inherits character set from calling command line, you must set `NLS_LANG` accordingly, for example like this:

```
C:\>chcp 1252
Active code page: 1252

C:\>set NLS_LANG=.WE8MSWIN1252

C:\>sqlplus ...

SQL> SELECT UNISTR( '\002D' ) AS HyphenMinus,
  2         UNISTR( '\2010' ) AS Hyphen,
  3         UNISTR( '\2011' ) AS NonBreakingHyphen,
  4         UNISTR( '\2012' ) AS FigureDash,
  5         UNISTR( '\2013' ) AS EnDash,
  6         UNISTR( '\2014' ) AS EmDash,
  7         UNISTR( '\2015' ) AS HorizontalBar,
  8         UNISTR( '\2043' ) AS HyphenBullet
  9  FROM   DUAL;

H H N F E E H H
- - - - - - - -
- - - ¿ – — ¿ ¿

SQL>
```

You see FigureDash, HorizontalBar and HyphenBullet are not supported by [CP1252](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1252), depending on your requirement you have to choose another character set, e.g. UTF-8

```
C:\>chcp 65001
Active code page: 65001

C:\>set NLS_LANG=.AL32UTF8
C:\>sqlplus ...
```

Have a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33783902/odbcconnection-returning-chinese-characters-as/33790600#33790600) to get some more information about `NLS_LANG` settings.

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple different hyphen/dash/minus characters:

```
SELECT UNISTR( '\002D' ) AS HyphenMinus,
       UNISTR( '\2010' ) AS Hyphen,
       UNISTR( '\2011' ) AS NonBreakingHyphen,
       UNISTR( '\2012' ) AS FigureDash,
       UNISTR( '\2013' ) AS EnDash,
       UNISTR( '\2014' ) AS EmDash,
       UNISTR( '\2015' ) AS HorizontalBar,
       UNISTR( '\2043' ) AS HyphenBullet
FROM   DUAL
```

Only `-` (`CHR(45)`) is within the base ASCII character set. If your column only supports this then the characters within the extended character sets may not display properly.

[Check what character set your database is using](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9703421/1509264) and you may need to either:

- [change the database's character set](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e10729/ch11charsetmig.htm#NLSPG011) to something that supports the characters you are using; or
- use a `NVARCHAR2` data type rather than `VARCHAR2`
- Only use the supported characters in your inputs (and reject any strings that contain chatacters in the extended character set).

Comment: Since SQL-Developer inserts characters properly 1st and 2nd proposal should not be valid. Apparently the database and used datatype supports desired characters properly.